# Required String parameter &#39;email&#39; is not present

Tags: angular, spring-mvc

I am trying to make simple project for my college. I am trying to send an email.

My controller in SPRING MVC

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/send-mail", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendEmailToClient(@RequestParam(name="email") final String email) {
        //some code
    }
}
```

My angular query

```
public sendEmail<T>(emailAddress: String) {
        return this.http.post<T>(this.getEmailUrl, {params: {
            email: emailAddress
        }})
            .catch(error => {
                throw new Observable(error)
            })
    }
```

But I got an error.

> POST http://localhost:8080/M.S.-Handloom-Fabrics/mail/send-mail 400 (Required String parameter 'email' is not present)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think you made a mistake in your `http.post(...)`. You forgot a parameter.**

According to **[Angular docs about HttpClient post](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post)**, this is the definition of `post` method:

```
post(url: string, body: any | null, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    observe?: 'body';
    params?: HttpParams | {
        [param: string]: string | string[];
    };
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType: 'arraybuffer';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<ArrayBuffer>
```

So you should have 3 parameters :

- **`url`** : `Type: string`.
- **`body`** : `Type: any | null`.
- **`options`** : `Type: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: 'body'; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType: 'arraybuffer'; withCredentials?: boolean; }.`

As you forgot one parameter, you're URL is good but your `params` is your `body` and you have no `options`.

### EDIT

Your code should be :

```
public sendEmail<T>(emailAddress: String) {
        return this.http.post<T>(this.getEmailUrl, {}, {params: {
            email: emailAddress
        }})
        .catch(error => {
            throw new Observable(error)
        });
}
```

Comment: B - How can do it then. Can you provide a correct code